# ROS Answers SE migration: rgbdslam_v2

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu12.04 hydro
exbot@ubuntu:~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash 
exbot@ubuntu:~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws$ rosdep install rgbdslam
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
exbot@ubuntu:~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/exbot/rgbdslam_catkin_ws
Source space: /home/exbot/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/exbot/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/exbot/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/exbot/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/install

##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/exbot/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build"

##### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/exbot/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build"

[  6%] [ 15%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_cpp
Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_py
[ 21%] [ 35%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_lisp
Built target siftgpu_proj
[ 35%] Built target rgbdslam_gencpp
[ 35%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages
[ 36%] [ 38%] [ 40%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_graph_manager.o
Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_openni_listener.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/main.o
Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.o
/tmp/ccdF4evG.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccdF4evG.s:10797: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r15),%xmm0,%xmm1' /tmp/ccdF4evG.s:12163: Error: no such instruction:` vfmadd312ss (%r15),%xmm0,%xmm1'
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_openni_listener.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/ccdtyevG.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccdtyevG.s:11191: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r15),%xmm0,%xmm1' /tmp/ccdtyevG.s:12557: Error: no such instruction:` vfmadd312ss (%r15),%xmm0,%xmm1'
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_graph_manager.o] Error 1
/tmp/ccvKbCtG.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccvKbCtG.s:15651: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r15),%xmm0,%xmm1' /tmp/ccvKbCtG.s:17017: Error: no such instruction:` vfmadd312ss (%r15),%xmm0,%xmm1'
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/main.o] Error 1
/tmp/ccvG4evG.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccvG4evG.s:439250: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r15),%xmm0,%xmm1' /tmp/ccvG4evG.s:440616: Error: no such instruction:` vfmadd312ss (%r15),%xmm0,%xmm1'
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207014/rgbdslam_v2/) by [Miku](https://answers.ros.org/users/22128/miku/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate of the following question, and has already been answered:
[RGBDSLAM V2 catkin_make error](http://answers.ros.org/question/190688/rgbdslam-v2-catkin_make-error/)

Please use the search function next time before posting a new question. Also, it can be helpful to add a short description of your problem at the beginning of your question. Thanks!

Edit: I saw you posted this question [again](http://answers.ros.org/question/207013/rgbdslam_v2-build-error/). Next time, please use the edit function if you have additional information to add...

---

Originally posted by [timm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6556/timm/) with karma: 376 on 2015-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0